# Can I render view without returning it in action controller in zend framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Now I am doing so:

```
public function indexAction() {
    ...
    $view = new ViewModel(array(
        'foo' => 'bar',
    ));
    return $view;
}
```

The problem is that I want to do something after $view rendering and before layout rendering:

```
public function indexAction() {
    ...
    $view = new ViewModel(array(
        'foo' => 'bar',
    ));
    $layout = $this->layout();

    $layout->content = $view->render();
    ...
    // here I want to do some important action
    ...
    $html = $layout->render();
    return $this->getResponse()->setContent($html);    
}
```

But there is no method render(). In ZF1 I could render view:

```
$view = new Zend_View($data);
$html = $view->render($templateName);
```

How can I do that in ZF2?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function IndexAction()
{
    ...
    $viewRender = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewRenderer');
    $html = $viewRender->render($viewModel);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Excellent, could you do this including the layout too?

Answer (score 15):

Complementing the answer, with layout included...

```
public function IndexAction() {
    ...
    $viewRender = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewRenderer');

    $layout = new ViewModel();
    $layout->setTemplate("layout/main");
    $layout->setVariable("content", $viewRender->render($viewModel));

    $html = $viewRender->render($layout);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Don't use $this->getServiceLocator() inside the controller, it's deprecated and bad practice. Use a factory to inject the ViewRenderer